# VBox .vdi resize succeeded. Still not able to store more data on the .vdi

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk-image, size

I'm using Virtual Box Version 6.1.34 on Linux Mint 20. I ran out of space on one of my virtual machines (Guest OS: Xubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on dynamic .vdi image). Was 10G, resized to 100G.

I attempted the following steps:

1. Shut down machine
2. Removed snapshots by making a clone and attached clone to machine of the guest
3. Increased size of dynamically allocated .vdi to 100G using the GUI (File->Manage Virtual Media)
4. Rebooted using the install CD
5. Used GParted to deactivate the corresponding extended partition, increase the partition size, acknowledge and activate it again
6. Verified resize using `sudo fdisk -l`, which showed me the new size (**100.4G**) of the partition
7. Removed install CD and rebooted guest
8. Verified resize using `sudo fdisk -l`, which showed me the new size (**100.4G**) of the partition again

However, the guest OS still issues disk full when I copy new data on the .vdi clone (e.g. `fallocate -l 1G dump.bin`). I suspect `/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root` to cause the issue as `df -h` shows still a size of **8.4G** with usage of **95%** for that device.

Comment: Did you resize the filesystem too (not just the containing partition)? e.g: `resize2fs` for `ext*`... depending on the filesystem, it may be possible to do this live / while mounted.

Comment: See Step 5, or do you mean that gparted is not the same as resize2fs? Also `fdisk -l` shows the new partition size.

Comment: As `fdisk` reports the new size, but `df` still reports the old size, I'd hazard a guess that GParted didn't do this task for you! (though I'm not familiar with it, so can't say for sure - i would have expected it to do this)... remember that the partition size is not linked in any way with the filesystem size, other than they're generally very close.

Comment: You mean it may be a gparted bug?

Comment: "_it may be a gparted bug_" - unlikely... if the filesystem is `ext*`, please try `resize2fs` on it - if it's something else, try the relevant tool.

Comment: So gparted increased the partition size but not the fs size. Incredible! Thank you for hinting me on that.